# Scala return value different than expected

Tags: scala, recursion

I'm learning Scala and writing a function (recursive) to count the number of parentheses: +1 for opening, -1 for closing, in order to match and balance all the parentheses in a list of chars. It should return 0 if the parentheses are balanced.

I came up with that (with numerous print statements to understand what's going on):

```
def countPar(charList: List[Char], count: Int): Int = {

  if (count < 0) {
    println("negative count, returning", count)
    count
  }
  else if (charList.isEmpty) {
    println("empty list, returning", count)
    count
  }
  else if (charList.head.equals('(')) {
    println("head is ", charList.head, " count + 1:", count + 1)
    count + countPar(charList.tail, count + 1)
  }
  else if (charList.head.equals(')')) {
    println("head is ", charList.head, " count - 1:", count - 1)
    count + countPar(charList.tail, count - 1)
  }
  else {
    println("head is ", charList.head, " count:", count)
    countPar(charList.tail, count)
  }
}

val parCount = countPar("(a(b)c)".toList, 0)

println(parCount)
```

The print statements *do* seem to confirm that the logic is working, yet the final return value is wrong:

```
(head is ,(, count + 1:,1)
(head is ,a, count:,1)
(head is ,(, count + 1:,2)
(head is ,b, count:,2)
(head is ,), count - 1:,1)
(head is ,c, count:,1)
(head is ,), count - 1:,0)
(empty list, returning,0)
parCount: Int = 4
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Why the `count +` in several of the recursive cases?

Comment: I'm keeping track of the number of parentheses and passing it as an argument. +1 for an opening one, -1 for a closing one.

Comment: Think about what the recursive call is supposed to return. Are you sure the `count +` isn't double-counting anything?

Comment: But now I see what you mean... No reason for that and that was the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is simply returning `count + countPar(charList.tail, count + 1)` instead of `countPar(charList.tail, count + 1)` (and similarly for closing parenthesis).

The point of your recursive function is that you update the count according to the head value, and pass it to the recursive call which will update it based on the tail value (and the recursive call will do the same thing, until the tail is empty). That means that the recursive call will return the correct result: no need to add anything to it.

edit:
I think it also becomes clearer once refactored like so (the important part is the one with the comment, I tried not to change your approach otherwise):

```
def countPar(charList: List[Char], count: Int): Int = {
  if (count < 0) {
    println("negative count, returning", count)
    count
  } else if (charList.isEmpty) {
    println("empty list, returning", count)
    count
  } else {
    val updatedCount =
      if (charList.head.equals('('))
        count + 1
      else if (charList.head.equals(')'))
        count - 1
      else
        count
    println(s"head is ${charList.head}, count: ${updatedCount}")
    // We see here that the reursive call is the same in the 3 cases: the
    // only difference is how we update the count
    countPar(charList.tail, updatedCount)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You're currently coding in a very imperative/object-oriented style. But this calls for a functional, recursive approach:

```
def isBalanced(string: List[Char], count: Int=0): Boolean = {
  if (count < 0) { false }  // We can only be balanced if ( precedes )
  else {
    string match {
      case Nil => count == 0  // Is the count 0? If so, however we got here was balanced!
      case '('::tail => isBalanced(tail, count + 1)  // ( prepended to some list
      case ')'::tail => isBalanced(tail, count - 1)  // ) prepended to some list
      case _::tail => isBalanced(tail, count)
    }
  }
}
```

Note that our outer function is answering the question with it's signature: given an arbitrary list of characters, is that list balanced? ('yes or no' implies a boolean: using an integer makes things complicated for users of this function.) As with all recursive functions, the function asks if the question can be trivially solved, and if not it does a little bit of work and then simply returns the result of the recursive call.

To do this we first define a **base case**. That is, if the list is empty, we simply return whether or not the count is 0. If it is, we know the parens are balanced.

Secondly, we define the **recursive cases**. Here we trust that `isBalanced` returns a correct result and only deal with the incremental different. These two lines handle that:

```
case '('::tail => isBalanced(tail, count + 1)
case ')'::tail => isBalanced(tail, count - 1)
```

In each, we increment or decrement our count accordingly. The final line (with `case _::tail`) handles all other cases, which shouldn't affect the final result.

Using Scala's powerful case-matching functionality (`match`), this is very easy. We can put a simple guard ahead of the match to ensure that once the balancing goes negative we quit early. Then it's a matter of pattern-mapping against the string input. This is *far* more clear than using endless if-else clauses.

Also note the trick to create a default param value, so you needn't pass in `0`. This clarifies your interface while allowing you to re-use the function.

To demonstrate correctness:

```
isBalanced("((()))".toList)  // true
isBalanced(")))(((".toList)  // false
isBalanced("(()())".toList)  // true
isBalanced("((()())".toList)  // false
isBalanced("Foo () bar ()".toList)  // true
```

A note on printing log lines: if you need to do this to trace how the case mapping is happening, or do arbitrary gymnastics within a case clause, you can do this:

```
def isBalanced(string: List[Char], count: Int=0): Boolean = {
  if (count < 0) { false }
  else {
    string match {
      case Nil => count == 0
      case '('::tail => {
        println("Found an open paren")
        isBalanced(tail, count + 1)
      }
      case ')'::tail => {
        println("Found a close paren")
        isBalanced(tail, count - 1)
      }
      case _::tail => isBalanced(tail, count)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you not use `case '(' :: tail => ...`?

Comment: @Clashsoft Yup! Thanks for simplifying it even more.

Comment: Also, I think you could add a `@tailrec` annotation, since the implementation is tail-recursive.

Comment: @Clashsoft I thought about that... but I think that the compiler might pick that up anyway, and annotations for compiler optimization were likely a step past where the OP was at, learning-curve-wise.